# How to locally debug multiple projects in anypoint studio

Tags: debugging, localhost, mule, mule-studio

I am working with two applications (let's call them A and B). Application A interacts with application B (calling with HTTP request connector). Can't figure out how to locally debug them both: start the process with application A and transition debugging (breakpoints) onto the other application B after HTTP request.

Manage to deploy applications locally with no problems. Did some reading about Domain project but I don't think that is what I need?

I keep getting this error

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
```

What I am trying to achieve is start data process with application A, reach HTTP request connector, transition to the next processor (F6), which means to the next application, and be able to follow the data in the application B. Is this something that is not possible today or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try modifying the log4j2.xml under `src/main/resources`:

```
    <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.module.http.internal.HttpMessageLogger" level="WARN"/>
```

to

```
    <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.module.http.internal.HttpMessageLogger" level="DEBUG"/>
```

Please update your post with the logs; hopefully we can help you out. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Was able to solve the problem - the issue was with the payload (json validation). WIll try to remember about logging levels next time I will be stuck